# protobuf post rpc method with string formatting

Tags: post, protocol-buffers, string-formatting

I have this rpc in my .proto file:

```
    message SetFlagRequest {
        string name = 1;
        bool enable = 2;
    }

    rpc SetFeatureFlag(SetFlagRequest) returns (FlagStatus) {
          option (google.api.http) = {
              post: "/v2/flags/{name}/{enable}"
              body: "*"
          };
//...
```

I would like to have post address of:

`"/v2/flags/{name}/enable"`  (for enable = true)  instead of `"/v2/flags/{name}/true"`

`"/v2/flags/{name}/disable"` (for enable = false)  instead of `"/v2/flags/{name}/false"`

is there a way of string formatting in `.proto` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, standard practice is to make them explicit.

```
message SetFlagRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

rpc EnableFeatureFlag(SetFlagRequest) returns (FlagStatus) {
      option (google.api.http) = {
          post: "/v2/flags/{name}/enable"
          body: "*"
      };

rpc DisableFeatureFlag(SetFlagRequest) returns (FlagStatus) {
      option (google.api.http) = {
          post: "/v2/flags/{name}/disable"
          body: "*"
      };
```

Then in your implementation of each you can call a common method if you like.